# C# Multiline textBox to .TXT file

Tags: c#

I'm definitely using the wrong method. Actually I'm trying to convert from JAVA to C# and it's beginning to become tough ..

Anyway, I have a textBox1 that is multiline, I write to it by for looping an ArrayList.

The textbox1 looks like this:

```
Website: https://google.dk
Firmanavn: Google LLC
Email: google@gmail.com
CVR: 123456
gScore: 1
gLink: googlePageSpeedLink
```

The code that I use right now, which manages to create a file, but it ends up empty. I am surely doing something wrong, and I'm unsure how to write the textBox to the file.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;


        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String path = Path.GetFullPath(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

            path = DialogResult.ToString();
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            { 

                File.WriteAllText(path, textBox1.Text);

                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated... :3 :3 I searched for around 1½ hours on StackOverFlow but I didn't manage to see a sample that would match my way of code :3

I hope it's not a duplicate question, thanks a lot for your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Stream:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = Path.GetFullPath(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

    File.WriteAllText(path, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was one easy fix... Was it only because of the stream or was it due to the double if conditions ?

Comment: It's because you are open the file twice, write to the file, close the file, and then close the stream which is empty.  Do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @GodLess What Jay mentioned is of course right, but I'm surprised your version even compiled, since `DialogResult.ToString()` is trying to do `.ToString()` on an Enum which from my Knowledge shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Oh wow, I really panicked a lot after playing around with a few different calls. At the end I did not even look at what I was doing... Luckily you clarified the issue and helped me out. Thanks a lot.